# Do I need to include my scaled outputs in my back-propagation equation (SGD)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation, derivative

Quick question, when I am backpropagating the loss function to my parameters and I used a scaled output (ex. tanh(x) * 2), do I need to include the derivative of the scaled output w.r.t the original output? Thank you!

Comment: Is loss calculated before or after scaling?

Answer (score 0):

Before we can backprop the errors, we've to compute the gradient of the loss function with respect to each of the parameters. This computation involves computing the gradients of the outputs first and then use chain rule repeatedly. So, when you do this, the scaling constant remains as is. So, yes, you've to scale the errors accordingly.

As an example, you might have observed the following [L2 regularized loss - a.k.a Ridge regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularized_least_squares#Ridge_regression_(or_Tikhonov_regularization)):

Loss = 1/2 * |T - Y|^2 + \lambda * ||w||^2

Here, we are scaling *down* the squared error. So, when we compute the gradient 1/2 & 2 would cancel out. If we would not have multiplied this by 0.5 in the first place, then we would have to scale up our gradient by 2. Else the gradient vector would point in some other direction instead of the direction which minimizes the loss.